WinUI 3 C# Frame control couldn't Navigate the WebView2 control in a page
I am new to WinUI 3, but I worked on WinForms app before. In WinForms, WebView2 has to be installed via NuGet, but it is included in WinUI 3.
I found that WebView2 in WinUi3 works normally in window(MainWindow), but If I add WebView2 to a page like:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Page
    <!--Some properties-->

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="9*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="Blue"/>
        <controls:WebView2 x:Name="Browser" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Source="https://www.google.com" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" DefaultBackgroundColor="Black"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>

And navigate the page in main window with Frame:
// Adding a Tab with Frame
muxc.TabViewItem NewTab = new();
Frame TabFrame = new();
NewTab.Content = TabFrame;
NewTab.Header = "New";
TabFrame.Navigate(typeof(TabPage));
TabControl.TabItems.Add(NewTab);

The window will look like the following image:
.
It shows the blue rectangle, which means the page loaded correctly. The part under the blue rectangle is WebView2, which doesn't even show with the DefaultBackgroundColor.
I used await Browser.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(); and Console.WriteLine(Browser.Parent.ToString()); to see if my WebView2 instance exists. The former snippet just keeps waiting and the latter throws a NullReferenceException. How can I fix this?

You don't need a namespace for WebView2.
<!--
<controls:WebView2 Source="https://www.google.com" />
-->
<WebView2 Source="https://www.google.com" />

UPDATE
I created a sample app and did reproduce your issue. You also need to set the TabView's VerticalAlignment to Stretch.
The following is the code that works on my side:
MainPage.xaml
<TabView
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    AddTabButtonClick="TabViewControl_AddTabButtonClick" />

MainPage.xaml.cs
private void TabViewControl_AddTabButtonClick(TabView sender, object args)
{
    var tabViewContent = new Frame();
    tabViewContent.Navigate(typeof(WebView2Page));

    var tabViewItem = new TabViewItem()
    {
        Header = "New Tab",
        Content = tabViewContent,
    };

    sender.TabItems.Add(tabViewItem);
    sender.SelectedItem = tabViewItem;
}

WebView2Page.xaml
<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*">
    <TextBlock
        Grid.Row="0"
        Text="WebView2" />
    <WebView2
        x:Name="WebView2Control"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Source="https://www.google.com" />
</Grid>


I tried it and webview2 still doesn't appear

You are right. I just updated my answer.

I just found that the reason for this bug is Webview2 doesn't work if you set the "Output Type" property of the app to "Console app". I will report the bug.
